ModuleNotFoundError (again...)
I'm working on a project in Visual Studio Code, coding in python. I wanted to import some extra modules (pandas, lumibot, alpaca_trade_api,...) and soon I found out that you need a virtual environment. So that's what I did. I installed a venv called myenv and after that, in the terminal in VSC I was clearly in the venv:
(myenv) C:\Users\thiba\Documents\prive\DT>
via the terminal in VSC I intalled the necessary modules, for example:
(myenv) C:\Users\thiba\Documents\prive\DT bot>pip install pandas
Everything went fine and the squiggly lines went away. However, when I try to run my file, I still get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
I tried looking at the paths and installing the modules again but everything seems fine.
Someone who can fix this? Thanks!

Does this answer your question? Unable to import a module that is definitely installed

Pandas must be installed into the same virtual environment that is used to run the program. If you're running it from an IDE, you need to understand how that IDE manages virtual environments, and should normally use the IDE's tools to install things rather than the command line.

Open any .py file. Then at the bottom right part of your vscode select the right interpreter(myvenv). Then run the program.
